# Have good way to python bottle web framework allow range of ip addresses?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ip, bottle

I want let some IPs can access to site.

**example :**

bottle server IP : `192.168.0.1`

and I want let `192.168.0.1/29` can access to site,

so `192.168.0.2` can access to site, `192.168.0.11` can't access to site.

---

my way is create a function to check client IP,

if out of range return status 403.

check IP function like this:

from netaddr import IPSet,IPAddress

def authIP(clientIP=None):

```
rules = IPSet(['192.168.0.1/29'])

if(IPAddress(clientIP) in rules):

    return 'ok.'
else:
    abort(403,'access denied.')
```

but, use this way,I will add this function to every route function to check it.

Like:

```
@route('/ip')
def tip():
    cip = request.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
    return authIP(cip)
```

Have any other ideas ...?

Comment: You have an approach that you say works.  Why are you looking for something else?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to find has any simple way  can doesn't need add check function to every route part...